# Auto updating a single plugin

Tags: automatic-updates

I have created a custom plugin and it is self hosted (not in the Wordpress repository). I am able to get WordPress to recognize when there are updates available for the plugin but I would like to have the plugin be auto updated on a site when an update is available.

I have this code in the plugin which actually does it - the only problem is it also auto updates any other plugin that is installed on the site, even though I specifically tell it to only update my plugin.

```
function auto_update_plugin ( $update, $item ) {
   // Array of plugin slugs to always auto-update
   $plugins = array ( 
     'my-custom-plugin'
   );
   if ( in_array( $item->slug, $plugins ) ) {
     return true; // Always update plugins in this array
   } else {
     return $update; // Else, use the normal API response to decide 
                     // whether to update or not
   }
}
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', 'auto_update_plugin', 10, 2 );
```

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: A WP CLI based solution would be much simpler, running `wp plugin update my-custom-plugin` on a server cron job would do the trick without any custom code

Comment: Of note, the code appears to be based on [the example in the codex here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates#Plugin_.26_Theme_Updates_via_Filter)

Comment: Thanks but I need to implement it within the plugin as I wouldn't have access to adding cron jobs on remote servers. And yes, the code I am using is based on what I found in the codex - hence why it seems strange it doesn't work as WordPress say it should.

Comment: Codex can be edited by anybody, and is out of date sometimes, for official docs look at https://developer.wordpress.org/

Comment: I don't see any documentation for that filter in the reference area on the developer site. Is this not a valid filter, even though it sort of works?